# Determining the number of days from today

Tags: datetime, ios, swift

Today I've got a pretty simple snippet to be reviewed. The function is extremely simple, as all it does is retrieve some entities from Core Data and then compares the `dueDate` attribute to today. I'm here asking about two questions:

1. Is this code reliable?
2. Is this the most efficient way (less lines of code) to accomplish this task?

The output will be separated into different arrays as seen by the comments inside the various `if` statements. The categories include:

- Greater than One Month
- One Month
- One Week
- Tomorrow
- Today

```
func fetchAssignments() {

    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Assignment")

    var error: NSError?

    let fetchedResults =
    managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest,
    error: &error) as! [NSManagedObject]?

    if let results = fetchedResults {
        for item in results {
            let dueDate = item.valueForKey("dueDate") as! NSDate
            let todayDate = NSDate()

            let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
            let calendarComponents: NSDateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: todayDate, toDate: dueDate, options: .allZeros)
            println("Days: " + calendarComponents.day.description + " Months: " + calendarComponents.month.description)
            if calendarComponents.month > 0 && calendarComponents.day > 0 {
                // Greater Than One Month
                return
            } else if calendarComponents.day > 7 {
                // One Month
                return
            } else if calendarComponents.day > 1 {
                // One Week
                return
            } else if calendarComponents.day == 1 {
                // Tomorrow
                return
            } else {
                // Today
                return
            }
        }
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I use similar code and I found some short cuts based off your code. The code I use has not given me any reliability issues as of yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the main error that I see: You compute the timespan between the "current date" and the "due date". If the current date is today at 11am, and the due date is tomorrow at 10am then the difference
is 0 days and 23 hours, to this is reported as "today".

This is probably not what you wanted, therefore `todayDate` must be
set to the *start of the current day*. This is easily done with

```
let todayDate = calendar.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
```

Then `todayDate` and `calendar` should be computed only once before the
loop starts, and not for each loop iteration.

There are also problems in the analysis of the computed date components:

```
if calendarComponents.month > 0 && calendarComponents.day > 0 { ...
```

What if the difference is exactly 2 (or more) month and 0 days?

```
} else if calendarComponents.day > 7 {
```

What if the difference is exactly one month and 0 days?

The first two if-conditions should therefore be

```
if calendarComponents.month >= 2 || (calendarComponents.month == 1 && calendarComponents.day > 0) {
    // More than a month
} else if calendarComponents.month == 1 || calendarComponents.day > 7 {
    // Between 8 days and one month
} else if ...
```

Other things that can be improved:

If you create a `NSManagedObject` subclass for your entity then
you can use the property accessors instead of `valueForKey()`:

```
let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest,
    error: &error) as! [Assignment]?

// ... later ...
let dueDate = item.dueDate
```

The advantage is that you don't need the cast `as! NSDate` anymore
and the compiler can check for correct types.

Some type annotations are not necessary, e.g.

```
let calendarComponents: NSDateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay,
    fromDate: todayDate, toDate: dueDate, options: .allZeros)
```

can be simplified to

```
let calendarComponents = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay,
    fromDate: todayDate, toDate: dueDate, options: nil)
```

And

```
println("Days: " + calendarComponents.day.description + " Months: " + calendarComponents.month.description)
```

can be simplified with string interpolation:

```
println("Days: \(calendarComponents.day) Months: \(calendarComponents.month)")
```

Comment: I appreciate your detailed analysis of my work, thank you. :)